# Why would I need a disk to transfer music?

Tags: usb-connection-mode, file-transfer

Why does Windows XP say "please insert a disk into drive F" when trying to transfer music?

(Samsung Galaxy S Aviator)

Comment: Some more information what you did would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

A screen should appear after you plug the device into your PC, when the device's usb connection is in "mass storage mode". Make sure to enable USB-mass storage there. This options unmounts the storage from you device and exposes it to the host PC.

Answer (score 0):

here are some instruction for your question :

1. Log in as Administrator account in windows or any other account with administrative privileges
2. Insert your removable disk into the USB port.
3. Click Start, now right click on my computer and select manage
4. Now, click Disk Management
5. Right click on your removable drive partition and select Change Drive Letter and Paths under Disk Management ( you can find your drive easily through size )
6. Change the drive letter some other drive letter like X: or Z: which is not reserved by some other drive on windows.

DONE :) to read more about this try looking : http://www.techyv.com/questions/pc-asks-insert-disk-drive-d

Comment: **or** he just didn't mount the card from the device. Given that he's using xp, it's far more likely.